# Error: Could not find or load main class -Xms1G

Tags: java, jvm-arguments, jvm-hotspot

After moving from spring to gradle, we're trying to redeploy an app to account for the change.  However, deployment has continuously failed, with this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class -Xms1G
```

The line of code in question is:

```
exec nohup "$JAVACMD" $JAVA_OPTS @EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS@ \
    -Xms1G -Xmx2G \
```

There is no reason for this to register as a class; we added this a while ago to alocate the memory, and the application worked and deployed fine.  When testing on a local environment, there are no issues, so I have no idea what is wrong.

Java's version is 1.8.0_172.

Comment: Moving from Spring to Gradle? I don't understand, they're two different things!

Comment: It looks like the name of the class you want to run is missing from the command line. You specify the Java command and options, but no classname of the class to run.

Comment: What values are being substituted for `$JAVACMD`, `$JAVA_OPTS`, and  `@EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS@`? In other words, what is the final java command being executed?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have problems with word wrapping, for example this line has the same output

```
$ java \ -Xmx1G
Error: Could not find or load main class  -Xmx1G
```

does it work if it's the single line? If it does, then pay attention on usage of the "\" symbol.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing.  In the gradle build file, we set up the options to be called.  We accidentally deleted the dash before the option, so it was read as a class. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.

@Boris the Spider:  your right, I meant maven to gradle. I don't know why I wrote Spring.  I'll correct that later, as I'm typing from my phone now.